# How to find these metrics in Google Analytics 4

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am using [Google Analytics Data API (GA4)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1) in [Python SDK](https://pypi.org/project/google-analytics-data/0.16.1/).

But I can find these dimensions:

- newVsReturning
- cartToViewRate
- purchaseToViewRate

I checked them in the [dimensions list of the documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/api-schema#dimensions).

But I want to know how to find these metrics on the web interface like `https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/#/analysis/...`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you edit your question and include [example]

Comment: if you have activated everything correctly, then you can see the info either in Explore or Reports menu